# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, hosting, laravel-5.5

I have install laravel 5.5 on my hosting server, and I got this error, I didn't know what should i doing, I have a look in google for this problem, but I not found it.
Please help me guys

Comment: What version of PHP are you using on your server?

Comment: I have run this in PHP 7.0

Comment: Try this in the project root command line. `find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep -v '^No syntax errors'`